# null and the symmetry of equals

Tags: java, null, nullpointerexception, equals, symmetric

Equality is supposed to be symmetric, right?

```
Object someObject = new Object();
Object NULL = null;

NULL.equals(someObject) => NullPointerException
someObject.equals(NULL) => false
```

What is the rationale for *not* having the second form throw a `NullPointerException`?

Comment: The statement `null.equals(someObject)` can't be compiled, at least by me.  How did you manage to compile it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it a bad idea if equals(null) throws NullPointerException instead?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2887761/is-it-a-bad-idea-if-equalsnull-throws-nullpointerexception-instead)

Comment: @Paul: It was obviously pseudo-code. Better now? :)

Comment: @Fred, Not really.  If you take 2 seconds and read the API for [`Object.equals()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals(java.lang.Object)) you'll see that the "equals method implements an equivalence relation on non-null object references."  You're asking "why doesn't Java behave like I think it should instead of how it's defined in the API?"  It might help if you read up on the definition of null.  I link to the Java language spec in my answer below.

Comment: @Paul: If "equals method implements an equivalence relation on non-null object references", then passing null should *definitely* throw an exception, because null is not non-null.

Comment: @Paul: I'm not asking why Java behaves as described in the API. I'm wondering why the API is defined like that in the first place. So far I haven't seen any convincing argument that throwing a `NullPointerException` when passing `null` to `equals` would be fundamentally wrong.

Comment: @Fred, you haven't made a convincing argument why it should throw an NPE.  I've explained why it wouldn't - the value of your object is not equal to the literal null reference.

Comment: @Paul: The argument is symmetry. I want `a.equals(b)` and `b.equals(a)` to mean the same.

Comment: @Fred, I think you're hung up on the idea that null is a value.  It's not.  It represents the null reference: a pointer to nothing.  `equals` is for comparing values; `==`  when used with Objects compares references.  As a bad analogy, it's like you're saying "I want my apple peeler to peel this orange".  The apple peeler tool is for apples, just as `equals` is for values.  Neither object nor primitive can have the value null; objects can have a reference of null.

Comment: @Paul: It seems you agree with me, after all: if equals is for comparing values, and null is not a value, then passing null to equals should be an error, right?

Comment: @Fred, I don't agree at all and having equals thrown an exception would be horrible to program with.  When calling `equals()` I only care about true and false. In years of programming I've never been concerned with the 3rd state: undefined (see [three-valued logic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_logic)). Do you want to wrap every call to equals in a try-catch block or check for null before calling `equals`? I sure the hell don't. If you need a 3-valued equals (which is what you're advocating...true, false, exception) then just check for null before you call equals or write an interface.

Comment: @Fred: Null is a value albeit an empty value (actually binary 0 at the lowest form of implementation).

Comment: @Paul: "having equals thrown an exception would be horrible to program with. [...] Do you want to wrap every call to equals in a try-catch block or check for null before calling equals?" But I have to do the null check for the reference on the left of the dot, anyway :) If you can show me a real world code snippet that benefits from equals(null) returning false instead of throwing an exception, I will upvote and accept your answer.

Comment: @Fred, every time I've ever used equals benefits from null->false. When I use equals I want to know 1 of 2 things: are they equal or not equal.  null->false meets that need.  I never want to know one of three things: are they equal, not equal, or undefined.  What case can you present where you need to know the 3rd state?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Equality is certainly defined to be symmetric in a theoretical sense, but it also *isn't defined at all on non-existent objects* (which is what null represents).

Hence any behaviour when applied to null would be equally valid. It could return a live rabbit and still not contradict the theoretical definition of equality.

In such a case, it's a pretty reasonable implementation decision on behalf of the designers of Java that calling equals on a null value should throw a NullPointerException, as that is consistent with calling any other method on a null value.

Comment: You would think that the exception would be different or that it wouldn't compile at all.

Comment: @0A0D - I think this is just a practical matter of being consistent - you want any dereference of a null pointer to throw a NullPointerException at runtime otherwise people will get confused about the possible causes....

Comment: I can see that. It just seems funny since it explicitly states that it is only in regards to non-null references. Since null is explicitly null here, one would think that the compiler would stop immediately. The value is already known prior to run-time.

Answer (score 4):

In the first case, the equals() method doesn't throw the NPE, so you can't make that argument. Symmetry is part of the contract of the equals() method.

Comment: Symmetry is part of the contract only for non-null values.

Comment: @Paul: True enough, however the question is *why* is that the case, and I'm pointing out that the premise of the question is flawed anyway because equals() didn't throw the NPE.

Answer (score 1):

Because you are not accessing a method of a `null` object in the second case. It's not the concept of equality that is unbalanced it's how you are accessing it.

Answer (score 0):

The second example is not an example of symmetry because it violates one of the simple rules in regards to Object and the [equals() method](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29):

> For any non-null reference value x, x.equals(null) should return
>   false.

Comment: Okay, but *why* is the contract defined like that? What do we gain from this asymmetry? Why doesn't it say "`x.equals(null)` should throw a `NullPointerException`"?

Comment: @FredOverflow: Because NullPointerException is a run-time exception and it does not make sense to throw an exception for something *exceptional* when it is following the rules of the Object.equals() contract.

Comment: @Fred, `null` is not a value so an Object cannot equal null any more than you can assigne `null` to a primitive.  When you do the check `if (x == null)` you're really checking the address the pointer references.

Comment: So the contract is defined not to throw an exception when comparing to null, because if comparing to null did throw an exception, it would violate the contract? That's not a very convincing argument. I could just as well say that if the contract were defined to throw an exception on null, then trowing that exception would comply perfectly fine with the contract.

Comment: @FredOverflow: It wouldn't make sense for NullPointerException because you are not dereferencing a null pointer.

Comment: The [API](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/NullPointerException.html) says: "Thrown when an application attempts to use null in a case where an object is required. These include: [...] Applications should throw instances of this class to indicate other illegal uses of the null object." In fact, I have seen many APIs that throw a NullPointerException when being passed null.

Comment: @Fred: Give me this weekend to research. I am afraid the only answer you may get is *because*.

Comment: @FredOverflow: Methods that act upon an *object* should throw NPE if given a null reference, while those which act upon *references* should recognize that a null reference *is* a reference, though it does not identify an object.  The `equals` asks "Does this reference identify an object which is equivalent to you".  If the reference identifies an object that could be equivalent, it may have to examine the details of the object to determine if it is equivalent, but if the reference doesn't identify an object of the proper type there's no reason for the code to examine the object itself at all.

Answer (score 0):

I would go for

```
someObject.equals(null);
```

> What is the rational for not having the second form throw a
>   NullPointerException?

In this case, it won't throw NullPointerException.

Here we are sure that the object on which `equals()` is going to invoke is `NOT NULL`.

Answer (score 0):

The second bit doesn't throw an NPE because you are not dereferencing a null pointer.  That code returns false because you are comparing a value to a non-value.

`equals(null)` will always return false because there is no such thing as a null value.  Neither Object nor primitive can have the value `null` since the concept doesn't exist in Java.  `null` is a literal that represents the null reference which is why we compare references, such as `if (obj == null)`.  See the Java language spec, [section 3.10.7](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/lexical.html#3.10.7).  In other words, you are comparing the *value* of `someObject` to the null reference.

You could make your own object, override `equals`, and return true but that would go against the definition in Object.