# Comparing two objects, either of which could be null

Tags: java

I have a function in one of my classes that compares itself with another instance of the same class - and finds out which variables differ. This is for the purpose of minimizing network load with a main database (by only uploading data that needs to be uploaded, instead of uploading the whole object).

For this, I have been trying to make use of the `object.equals()` function to compare the two objects.

I soon found that the `object.equals()` does not handle `null`s, and after reading [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2887761/is-it-a-bad-idea-if-equalsnull-throws-nullpointerexception-instead), I understand why.

So an example of my broken code is as follows:

```
public class MyObject {

    String myString;
    String myString2;

    public String getChangedVars(MyObject comparisonObj) {
        ArrayList<String> changedVars = new ArrayList<String>();

        if (!this.myString.equals(comparisonObj.myString))
            changedVars.add("myString");
        if (!this.myString2.equals(comparisonObj.myString2))
            changedVars.add("myString2");

        return changedVars.toString();
    }
}
```

My question is - on the basis that *either* one of the variables being compared *could* be null, what is a simple way to compare two variables whilst avoiding a `NullPointerException`?

Edit:
Simply checking for null on both objects first doesn't work well, as I *still* want to compare if the object has a reference or not. Eg, if one item is `null` and the other is not, I want this to resolve to `true`, as the variable *has changed*.

Comment: Check for `null` first, on both objects.

Comment: Java 7: java.util.Objects.equals(Object a, Object b)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

There is new utility class available in jdk since 1.7 that is [`Objects`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html) .

> This class consists of static utility methods for operating on
>   objects. These utilities include null-safe or null-tolerant methods
>   for computing the hash code of an object, returning a string for an
>   object, and comparing two objects.

You can use `Objects.equals`, it handles null.

> Objects.equals(Object a, Object b) Returns true if the arguments are equal to each other and false
>   otherwise. Consequently, if both arguments are null, true is returned
>   and if exactly one argument is null, false is returned. Otherwise,
>   equality is determined by using the equals method of the first
>   argument.

```
if(Objects.equals(myString,myString2)){...}
```

Comment: Aah .. Something new. +1.

Comment: What a shame, this solution is great - unfortunately I don't seem to have access to the `Objects` class within Android - however as I didn't specify that this was an Android question (I honestly didn't think it was relevant) - then I will accept this answer anyway. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use Apache object utils

`ObjectUtils.equals(Object object1, Object object2)`  -- Returns boolean

this method has been replaced by java.util.Objects.equals(Object, Object) in Java 7

Answer (score 0):

```
    if (this.myString != null && this.myString.equals(comparisonObj.myString))
{
                changedVars.add("myString");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use StringUtils provided by apache

```
StringUtils.equals(myString,comparisonObj.myString);
```