# Error-prone Java enum refactoring

Tags: java, enums, findbugs

I'm refactoring some old code to use `enum`'s instead of `String` constants. I was reviewing my code when I noticed that comparing `enum` to `String` won't throw an exception. I can't delete the old constants because other projects are still using them.

I can't override the equals because JLS specifically forbids this:

> The equals method in Enum is a final method that merely invokes
>   super.equals on its argument and returns the result, thus performing
>   an identity comparison.

The code looks like this:

```
public enum Gender{
    MALE,
    FEMALE
}

// Constants for genders
public static final String MALE = "Male";
public static final String FEMALE = "Female";

//following are obviously false
MALE.equals(Gender.MALE) 
Gender.MALE.equals(MALE)
```

For a regular object I could override equals and throw an exception but for my example it will just return false. Also there was a method like getGender that was returning string and now is return an enum so there can be places I missed and a string is compared to enum

This is error-prone. FindBugs is also not reporting any bug.
Is there anyway I can protect against this?

Comment: You can use `==` with enums.

Comment: my question is in case I missed something

Comment: But don't you have type checking where you pass these constants? I.e. methods that expect `String` will compile-time shout that you are passing an enum to them? Or are you just using `Object` or raw lists?

Comment: there was a method like getGender and was returning a string; now it's returning an enum so the code still works

Comment: @RealSkeptic You could pass `CONSTANT.name()`.  But if the method expects a `String`, you're not fully realizing the advantages of using `enum`.  The method should expect a `Gender`.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels yes but for an regular object you can catch this in equals and throw an exception; for an enum I can't; it will just return false

Comment: @KevinKrumwiede I think you mistake what I ask. I am not thinking of a way to bypass the incompatibility - that's not what the OP is asking. I'm thinking of a way to use type safety to help prevent such a mixup.

Comment: "for an regular object you can catch this in equals and throw an exception" - You can, but you shouldn't.  When passed the wrong type, your overridden `equals(...)` methods should return `false` just like `enum`'s does.

Comment: I cannot tell what you're really asking for.  Do you want a way to write this "refactoring" class so that the confusion doesn't happen?  Do you want a way to separate the use of the enum from the uses of the strings?  Do you want a way to write this so that uses of the String will show errors when they start getting mixed with the use of the enum?  What?

Comment: Throwing an exception (other than NPE) from `equals` definitely breaks the principle of least astonishment (and the [contract](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals(java.lang.Object))).

Comment: @arcy just a way of catching if I missed something like obj.getGender().equals("Male") when getGender returns an enum

Comment: @KevinKrumwiede is completely correct: you should never be throwing exceptions from equals.

Comment: @MickMnemonic It shouldn't even throw NPE.  If you pass `null`, it should just return `false`.  That's what SDK classes do, and what `equals(...)` methods generated by Eclipse do.

Comment: @KevinKrumwiede, I agree that the contract doesn't mention throwing a NPE and doing so would be against the convention. However, one could also argue that the contract itself is broken. Good discussion on the topic in [Is it a bad idea if equals(null) throws NullPointerException instead](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2887761/is-it-a-bad-idea-if-equalsnull-throws-nullpointerexception-instead).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As noted in the comments, `Object#equals(...)` is not typesafe.  There's nothing you can do to prevent users of your API from passing it an object of the wrong type.  In that situation, it should simply return `false`.  If someone does this, eventually they'll notice that it's always returning false and go looking for the bug.

You should deprecate the `String` constants to draw attention to the preferred way of doing things:

```
/**
 * New code should use {@link Gender#MALE}.
 */
@Deprecated
public static final String MALE = "Male";
/**
 * New code should use {@link Gender#FEMALE}.
 */
@Deprecated
public static final String FEMALE = "Female";
```

Comment: Compiling with `javac -Xlint:deprecation` will issue warnings on all uses of `@Deprecated` items (and there are also options for these in Eclipse etc.), which will help eliminate missed occurrences where the string was not replaced with the enum.

Answer (score 2):

I would do something like this:

```
public enum Gender {
    MALE("Male"),
    FEMALE("Female");

    private final String val;

    Gender(String val) {
        this.val = val;
    }

    public static Gender getEnum(String value) {
        for (Gender a : values()) {
            if (a.getVal().equalsIgnoreCase(value)) {
                return a;
            }
         }
         return throw new IllegalArgumentException("no gender known");
    }

     public String getVal() {
         return val;
     }
}
```

It allows you to create an instance of the enum from a string and then compare the enum

```
Gender genderFromString = Gender.getEnum(someString);
genderFromString.equals(Gender.MALE);
```

By converting the string to an instance of the enum and then comparing the 2 enums, a more reliable result is obtained

Answer (score 1):

You could move the final String variables into a separate class, say `StringConstants`.

```
public class StringConstants {
    public static final String MALE = "Male";
    public static final String FEMALE = "Female";
}
```

Then in your code it would be a more obvious mistake when someone tries to compare `StringConstants.MALE` to `Gender.MALE`.

Also, renaming the enum to `GenderEnum` could help even further, because then it would be even more obvious that you don't want to do `GenderEnum.MALE.equals(StringConstants.MALE)`.

Comment: Moving them would break source compatibility.  The OP mentions that other projects are using these constants, so that would be very bad.

Comment: True, but with most modern IDEs, it would be quite simple to find all usages of the String constants and prepend `StringConstants`.

Comment: You should never force other developers to do that.  Once a public API is out of alpha, you should consider it carved in stone.  Changing it looks extremely incompetent and unprofessional.  The only time you should ever make breaking changes to a public API is when you bump the major version number.  And even then, only do it when necessary to enable functional changes, never just to reorganize or rename things.