# Overriding equals for CopyOnWriteArraySet.add and remove

Tags: java, equals, copy-on-write

I have classes like below

```
class A {
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object other) { return true }
}

Class B extends A {
}

Class C extends A {
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object other) { if ((other != null) || (other instanceOf B)) return false; }
}

In my main() I have this following code
Set<A> mySet = new CopyOnWriteArraySet<A>();

mySet.add(C);
I want mySet to contain C at this point

mySet.add(B); // #1
I want mySet to contain C & B at this point

mySet.remove(B); // #2
I want mySet to contain C at this point
```

I want to create a global queue where if object C exists in the queue B should be allowed to be added but not the other way around. So before #1 I am looping through the elements inside the set doing element.equals(B) with add on false.

But
1 is calling B.equals(C) which is returning true and so mySet has only one C object after this line

2 is again calling B.equals(C) which is returning true and removing the existing object C. Shouldn't it be C.equals(B) in this case? I am expecting this line as no-action

Is this some wrong use of CopyOnWriteArraySet?

Thanks for looking

Comment: Well your `equals` method is implemented incorrectly, so all sorts of things in the Collections API which rely on `equals` are going to behave unexpectedly.

Comment: equals must be associative as documented in Object.equals() i.e. a.equals(b) == b.equals(a) otherwise you will get confusion.

Comment: Also, `Object.equals(null)` should always return `false`.

Comment: Let me rephrase my question on what I am intending to do in my case

Comment: @PeterLawrey That's symmetric, not associative

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HashSet is the correct collection for my case. It won't call equals while adding elements unless there is hashCode match. That way I can still use my equals methods for my specific purpose.

Answer (score 2):

It is correct behavior it finds the element which is `equal()` so it removes first element

> Removes the specified element from this set if it is present. More formally, removes an element e such that `(o==null ? e==null : o.equals(e))`, if this set contains such an element. Returns true if this set contained the element (or equivalently, if this set changed as a result of the call). (This set will not contain the element once the call returns.) [...](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArraySet.html#remove%28java.lang.Object%29)

Comment: True. But my intention is to allow B to be added when C is in the set and not the other way around. Also I want to remove B or C with remove(B) and remove(C) and not randomly. My question is if this copyonwritearrayset is the right collection class for my task?

Comment: `Set` doesn't allow duplicate, it checks duplicate based on `equals()` and (`hashcode()` in case of hash based datastructure), if you want it to allow duplicate switch to `List`

Comment: I used CopyOnWriteArrayList but the problem is when I call add(C) and add(B) the list has two elements and when I do a remove(B) it is removing C instead.

Comment: because `B` `equals` `C` I doubt it even added `C`

Comment: List won't call equals while adding elements

Comment: HashSet worked in my case. It won't call equals unless the hashCode matches.